# C++ Standard: Strange signed/unsigned arithmetic division behavior for 32 and 64 bits

Tags: c++, standards, division, integer-arithmetic

I encountered a wrong behavior of my code. Investigating it leads me to a short example which shows the problem:

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<short> v(20);

    auto D = &v[5] - &v[10];   
    auto C = D / sizeof(short);

    std::cout << "C = " << C;

}
```

The example is a quite common. What is the result it will print?

```
C = 9223372036854775805
```

Tested here: https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc
Tested also for **Clang C++**, **VS C++** and **C**. Result the same.

Discussing with colleagues I was pointed to the document https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions .

It tells:

- If both operands are signed or both are unsigned, the operand with lesser conversion rank is converted to the operand with the greater integer conversion rank
- Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's conversion rank is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the signed operand, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type.
- Otherwise, if the signed operand's type can represent all values of the unsigned operand, the unsigned operand is converted to the signed operand's type

It seems the **second** rule is working here. But it is **not** true.

To confirm the **second** rule, I have tested such example:

```
//g++  5.4.0
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
            typedef uint32_t u_t; // uint64_t, uint32_t, uint16_t uint8_t
            typedef int32_t i_t;  // int64_t, int32_t, int16_t int8_t

            const u_t B = 2;
            const i_t X = -1;

            const i_t A1 = X * B;
    std::cout << "A1 = X * B = " << A1 << "\n";

            const i_t C = A1 / B;  // signed / unsigned division
    std::cout << "A1 / B = " << C << "\n";
}
```

with different *rank* combinations of *u_t* and *i_t* and found that it works correctly for any combination, **EXCEPT** for *32* and *64* bits (*int64_t/uint64_t* and *int32_t/uint32_t*). So the *second* rule **DOES NOT** work for *16* and *8* bits.

Note: the *multiplication* operation is working correct for all cases. So it is only **division** problem.

Also the **SECOND** rule sounds like it is wrong:

> the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type

The *signed* cannot be converted to *unsigned* - it is an **!! error !!** for **NEGATIVE** values!!
But opposite conversion is correct - *the unsigned operand is converted to the signed operand's type*

Looking at this I can note that here is a possible mistake in the C++ Standard Arithmetic operations. 
Instead of:

`Otherwise, if the unsigned operand's conversion rank is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the signed operand, the signed operand is converted to the unsigned operand's type.`

it SHALL be:

`Otherwise, if the signed operand's conversion rank is greater or equal to the conversion rank of the unsigned operand, the unsigned operand is converted to the signed operand's type.`

On my opinion, if *signed* and *unsigned* *multiplication*/*division* is met then *unsigned* operand is converted to *signed* and after that it is casted to correct rank. At least the *x86 Assembler* follows it.

Please, explain me where here is an error. I want the first test in this post works correct for any type involved in place of the **auto** type, but now it is **not** possible and the *C++ Standard* tells that it is correct behavior.

Sorry for a strange question, but I am in a stuck with the problem. I am coding on C/C++ for 30 years but it is first problem I cannot explain it clearly - whether it is a bug or an expected behavior.

Comment: `sizeof(short)` is of type `std::size_t` (unsigned).

Comment: `auto C = -5 / 2UL;` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to chew on here... I'll address only one point as you forgot to actually *ask a question*.

In your second code snippet:

```
const u_t B = 2;
const i_t X = -1;
const i_t A1 = X * B;
```

you see than `A1` is -2 and conclude that in the expression `X * B` both operands are promoted to signed integers. This is not true.

In `X * B`, both operands are promoted to unsigned integers, as per the Standard, but its result is then converted to a signed integer with the affectation `const i_t A1 = ...`.

You can easily check that:

```
const u_t B = 2;
const i_t X = -1;
const auto A1 = X * B; // unsigned
```

---

You can also play with `decltype(expression)` and [`std::is_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    signed s = 1;
    unsigned u = 1;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "  signed *   signed is signed? " << std::is_signed_v<decltype(s * s)> << "\n"
              << "  signed * unsigned is signed? " << std::is_signed_v<decltype(s * u)> << "\n"
              << "unsigned *   signed is signed? " << std::is_signed_v<decltype(u * s)> << "\n"
              << "unsigned * unsigned is signed? " << std::is_signed_v<decltype(u * u)> << "\n";
}

/*
  signed *   signed is signed? true
  signed * unsigned is signed? false
unsigned *   signed is signed? false
unsigned * unsigned is signed? false
*/
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e01140675f47904)

Comment: Try your example with other integral types. 
Instead of

    signed s = 1;
    unsigned u = 1;

try

```
    int16_t s = 1;
    uint16_t u = 1;
```

and the result will be:

```
  signed *   signed is signed? true
  signed * unsigned is signed? true
unsigned *   signed is signed? true
unsigned * unsigned is signed? true
```

The C++ Standard tells nothing about such difference.
For the rank 8 and 16 the multiplication type is *signed*, but for 32 and 64 it is *unsigned*.

Comment: Try your example with other integral types. 

Instead of 
`
signed s = 1;
 unsigned u = 1;
`
 try
`
 int16_t s = 1;
 uint16_t u = 1;
`
 and the result will be:

`
 signed * signed is signed? true
 signed * unsigned is signed? true
 unsigned * signed is signed? true
 unsigned * unsigned is signed? true
` 

The C++ Standard tells nothing about such difference. 

For the rank 8 and 16 the multiplication type in fact is *signed*, but for 32 and 64 it is in fact *unsigned*. 
Why?

Comment: Try it with 16 bits:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a09b9395c09b930b

The result is *true* for all.

32-bits and 16-bits has different behavior. There it is described in the C++ Standard?

Comment: @vlad this is why you shoud ask a question (and one only)

Comment: Agree, one question will be much simpler to discuss. 
But in this post I want to discuss a possible mistake in the C++ Standard which s widely implemented in almost every C++ compiler. 
I see the problem from many points of view and try to show all of them.

Comment: @VladimirProkofev The Standard cannot be wrong, unless it is inconsistent. Tip: Ask a new question and tag it [tag:language-lawyer]. Be sure to actually ask a question and one only. You should get better answers.